# How to implement Twirk (Twitch Chat IRC library) into an Android App?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build an android app that uses Twirk (a library that can be found at https://github.com/Gikkman/Java-Twirk ) that will read out-loud messages when a button is clicked. I am having issues making the program connect to Twitch and relay the messages.

I created a mockup program in Eclipse and used basically the same code that I am using here, and I got very promising results, with the bot connecting to the twitch streams and relaying all the messages for me

```
private class ConnectToTwitch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... channel) {
            try {
                final Twirk twirk = new TwirkBuilder("#" + channel, "mrandroid", "oauth:*******************").build();
                twirk.connect();


                //Check to see if a Talker has spoken and add them to the queue to speak when needed
                twirk.addIrcListener(new TwirkListener() {
                    public void onPrivMsg(TwitchUser sender, TwitchMessage message) {
                            messages.add(sender.getDisplayName() + " said: " + message.getContent());
                    }
                });
                //Check to see if new people are online and add them to the list of viewers
                twirk.addIrcListener(new TwirkListener() {
                    public void onNamesList(Collection<String> usersColl) {
                        users = usersColl.toArray(users);
                        Arrays.sort(users);
                    }
                });
            }catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("oopsie");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The program should connect to the twitch chat (with my chat bot appearing in the chat list on the channel) and start relaying messages whenever the button is clicked, but it doesn't ever appear in chat or relay any messages